# How to match the font "Helvetica" to "Adobe Helvetica"

Tags: opensuse, fontconfig

I'am using OpenSuse 12.2 and installed various font-packages. Fontconfig is triggered by SuSEConfig. So far, the installation seems ok. But I have the following problem:

I have to use the font "Helvetica", but I am getting Arial. I've run the following tests:

```
> fc-match "Helvetica"
arial.ttf: "Arial" "Normal"
> fc-match "Adobe Helvetica"
helvR12-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: "Adobe Helvetica" "Regular"
```

The first command should not return Arial as font, or am I wrong? Even if Arial is in a way the right answer, how can I configure the font system to return "Adobe Helvetica"?